# Sum of nested object values in Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

**I want to get sum of *exercise***. I'm trying to get sum of exercise of both Course array element.** 
Trying to use reduce method on individual array element but cant get sum.
I tried forOf and forIn loop to do but i'm not able to solve this problem.

```
const courses = [
{
  name: "Half Stack application development",
  id: 1,
  parts: [
    {
      name: 'Fundamentals of React',
      exercises: 10,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Using props to pass data',
      exercises: 7,
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'State of a component',
      exercises: 14,
      id: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'Redux',
      exercises: 11,
      id: 4
    }
  ]
}, 
{
  name: "Node",
  id: 2,
  parts: [
    {
      name: 'Routing',
      exercises: 3,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Middleware',
      exercises: 7,
      id: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

]

Comment: Please post the code of your attempts, otherwise we can't help you improve them.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `map` and `reduce` combined to get your exercise total per course.

```js
const courses = [
{
  name: "Half Stack application development",
  id: 1,
  parts: [
    {
      name: 'Fundamentals of React',
      exercises: 10,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Using props to pass data',
      exercises: 7,
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'State of a component',
      exercises: 14,
      id: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'Redux',
      exercises: 11,
      id: 4
    }
  ]
}, 
{
  name: "Node",
  id: 2,
  parts: [
    {
      name: 'Routing',
      exercises: 3,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Middleware',
      exercises: 7,
      id: 2
    }
  ]
}
]

const sum = courses.reduce((acc, course) => {
  acc[course.name] = course.parts.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.exercises, 0);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I want to get sum of exercise separately of  Course Name: Half Stack application development", and  "Node".

Comment: Sure... updated for this requirement! Let me know if it should be in a different format

Comment: Its work but i dont want to display value like : 4210 , I want get like this : Half Stack application development: 42 and  Node: 10

Comment: Is there any way i can share you my code? I tries several ways to solve it but unable to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202534/discussion-between-nirmal-patel-and-nick).

Answer (score -2):

Think the steps, and here the hints:

1. sum exercises for each course first
2. sum all exercises for all courses

#### 1. Sum exercises for each course

The idea here is to create a new array of exercises count for each course

```
exercises_courses = courses.map(item => {
  item.parts.reduce((sum, part) => sum + part.exercises, 0)
})
```

#### 2. Sum all exercises

```
all_exercises = exercises_courses.reduce((sum, exercises_course) => sum + exercises_course, 0)

console.log(all_exercises)
```

Comment: I want to get sum of both array element separately.

Comment: so, the first step is enough